# Is there a way to see in which system I've purchased goods?

Tags: eve-online

I just bought something at a different system and I can't remember which. Is there an easy way to see which system I have goods that I already purchased at?

Comment: What? What system?

Comment: It is a valid question. He doesn't know which system. It's the whole point. He's just looking for a way ingame to show him in which system(s) he's made purchases.

Comment: @resorath just in case you're not familiar with the game, by system he means solar systems.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the Wallet and Load the Transactions.  If you have trouble finding your purchase, use the filters - especially Item Type.

Right click on your purchase, and you can work with the Location (Show Info, Set Destination, Add Waypoint, Save Location).

Comment: Worth noting the wallet will only store history for a couple of months.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [assets panel](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Assets) which you can use to find all the items you own. While it won't directly tell you, you can search through the list of systems with items and look for one with a low number of items in them. There is basic filtering which may help you in your search if you happen to have a lot of items strewn about the place.

If you know what you purchased, you may also be able to use the search tab in that panel to find it, if it's not something very common like ore.

Comment: The assets panel does take time to update though, so, not always accurate. Better is defintely - on the wallet click transactions tab  - right click the transaction and then Set Destination.